# Does Cassandra JDBC provide a DataSource?

Tags: java, jdbc, cassandra, datasource

I have a large amount of legacy code that relies on being able to pass around a DataSource instead of a Connection object. I can see sample code for making a connection, ie:

```
Class.forName("org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:cassandra:root/root@localhost:9160/MyKeyspace");
```

However I can't see from the documentation any way to create a DataSource. Am I going to have to write my own DataSource to wrap the above code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use BasicDataSource class of Apache Commons DBCP http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/ which is a DataSource implementation that can work with any JDBC driver. See usage example here http://www.kodejava.org/how-do-i-create-a-basicdatasource-object/

Comment: But still you need to provide implementation DataSource implementation class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CassandraDataSource class.
https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-jdbc/source/browse/src/main/java/org/apache/cassandra/cql/jdbc/CassandraDataSource.java